# VSFTP Veracrypt mounted container - 550 Failed to change directory

Tags: permissions, mount, ftp, vsftpd, veracrypt

VERACRYPT CONTAINERS CAN NOT BE ACCESSED BY FTP ON LINUX/UNIX - VERACRYPT CONTAINERS CAN BE ACCESSED BY FTP ON WINDOWS.  VERACRYPT CONTAINERS MAY BE ACCESSED ON LINUX VIA SAMBA (AT YOUR OWN RISK - SAMBA WILL REGULARLY CREATE I/O ERRORS FOR MOUNTED VERACRYPT CONTAINERS.) hope this helps someone from spending days trying to do something that is not yet possible with linux and veracrypt - cheers

References:
https://pastebin.com/wwHcHeEv

Im attempting to access (read/write) a veracrypt mounted container by ftp.  I can access the veracrypt mount both by /media/veracrypt (default mount point of veracrypt folders).... and by /var/ftp/ftpd/ftpntfs the bind mount locally.

```
~# mount --bind /media/veracrypt6 /var/ftp/ftpd/ftpntfs 
~# umount /var/ftp/ftpd/ftpntfs
```

I can also see /var/ftp/ftpd/ftpntfs by ftp but when veracrypt is mounted i get a 550 error changing to the /var/ftp/ftpd/ftpntfs directory.  When veracrypt is not mounted /var/ftp/ftpd/ftpntfs is an accessible empty folder.

vsftpd.conf

```
listen_ipv6=YES
#
# Allow anonymous FTP? (Disabled by default).
anonymous_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this to allow local users to log in.
local_enable=YES
ftp_username=ftpd
#

write_enable=YES
#
# Default umask for local users is 077. You may wish to change this to 022,
# if your users expect that (022 is used by most other ftpd's)
#local_umask=022
#

#anon_upload_enable=YES
#

#anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES

dirmessage_enable=YES

use_localtime=YES
#
# Activate logging of uploads/downloads.
xferlog_enable=YES
#
# Make sure PORT transfer connections originate from port 20 (ftp-data).
connect_from_port_20=YES

#chown_uploads=YES
#chown_username=whoever

#xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log

#xferlog_std_format=YES

#idle_session_timeout=600

#data_connection_timeout=120

#nopriv_user=ftpsecure

#async_abor_enable=YES

#ascii_upload_enable=YES
#ascii_download_enable=YES

# chroot_list_enable below.
#chroot_local_user=YES
#

#chroot_local_user=YES
#chroot_list_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list

# Customization

# This option should be the name of a directory which is empty.  Also, the
# directory should not be writable by the ftp user. This directory is used
# as a secure chroot() jail at times vsftpd does not require filesystem
# access.
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty

pam_service_name=vsftpd

rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=NO

#utf8_filesystem=YES
```

I edited the [vsftpd.conf][1] file due to how long it is and how long editing "code" in forum takes i posted it to pastebin and will edit the conf file here if i figure the answer or someone helps "neatly" solve this apparently, from google and ask forum searches, an unsolved repeatedly asked problem.

```
/var/ftp/ftpd/ftpntfs/ is mounted to veracrypt mounted folder
~# mount --bind /media/veracrypt6 /var/ftp/ftpd/ftpntfs
```

~/ftpntfs can be accessed locally via nautilus and command line but via ftp the ~/ftpntfs folder is visible but not accessible

(display output)

```
150 Here comes the directory listing.
drwx------    1 0        0            4096 May 11 03:05 ftpntfs
-rwxrwxrwx    1 0        0            7784 May 07 22:36 vsftpd-f3067736.txt
226 Directory send OK.
ftp> cd ftpntfs
550 Failed to change directory.
```

tried

```
~# chown -R ftpd:ftpd /media/veracrypt6/
~# chown 777 /var/ftp/ftpd/ftpntfs
~# chown 777 /media/veracrypt6
~# chown -R ftpd:ftpd /var/ftp/ftpd/ftpntfs/
```

for interest I tried:

```
~# chgrp -R ftpd /var/ftp/ 
~# cd ~/ftpntfs/ 
bash: cd: /root/ftpntfs/: No such file or directory
```

and

```
~# ls -ld /var/ftp/
drwxr-xr-x 3 root ftpd 4096 May  8 03:43 /var/ftp/
```

I must be doing something wrong but not sure what.any suggestions appreciated

[1]: https://pastebin.com/xFAER385 - edited vsftpd.conf 
  # chown -hR ftpd /var/ftp/
seems to successfully change ownership for /var/ftp when chown and chmod dont work (chown -hR is from chown --help)
but this creates the error

```
500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()
Login failed
ftp> cd ftpntfs
421 Service not available, remote server has closed connection
```

the fix for THIS IS  - google liquidweb with the below code (i dont have priv. to post more links but identical fix is relatively easy to find)

```
:#echo 'allow_writeable_chroot=YES' >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
```

OR 
just add

```
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

somewhere in vsftpd.conf file 
but this does not resolve the 550 ftp error